# Why am I getting Mount Error (121), Remote I/O Error?

Tags: networking

I followed the instructions on this web page to setup a shared folder on a Windows 7 computer so I could access it on a computer running Ubuntu 16.04.1.
http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/

After setting it up, I pasted the mount command into the terminal on the Ubuntu machine and pressed enter. I got the following error. I am a new Ubuntu user and I have no idea what is causing this error. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!!

```
howard@howard-AY639AA-ABA-CQ5302F:~$ sudo mount.cifs //fx4130server/linux_share /home/howard/Desktop/Windows-Share -o user=howard
[sudo] password for howard: 
Password for howard@//fx4130server/linux_share:  ******
mount error(121): Remote I/O error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
howard@howard-AY639AA-ABA-CQ5302F:~$
```

I can connect to the folder on other computers running Windows on my network with no problems.

Answer (score 17):

Try adding `vers=2.1` in your option string:

```
sudo mount.cifs //fx4130server/linux_share /home/howard/Desktop/Windows-Share -o user=howard,vers=2.1
```

Comment: My Raspberry Pi used to be able to communicate with my Windows computer's network shares just fine but it suddenly stopped working. Adding `vers=2.1` fixed the problem.

Comment: My Ubuntu in VM used to be able to communicate with my Windows host network shares just fine but it suddenly stopped working after putting the VM to sleep and restoring it. Adding vers=2.1 fixed the problem.

Comment: Connecting from a Linux Mint box to a win7 machine. Adding the `vers=2.1` option allowed to successfully mount the share.